# Can I change the browser resolution on a mac with retina display?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, resolution, web-browser

I have to use a virtual desktop client for my job and the client sets the resolution of the stream to the resolution of the browser, which is substantially less than the number of pixels available (because I'm using a retina display), so the picture ends up looking blurry. Is there a way to force my browser to render at a different resolution without changing my whole display to render at that resolution?

Comment: The browser doesn't have a resolution - it renders it's content based on what the system is set to.  The client simply passes the screen resolution to the server to stream.  Normally, you can override the default resolution to something more appropriate - what virtual desktop client are you working with?  Also, for something like this, you'd want to check with your IT department because they can assist with how things are streamed from the server end.

Comment: I'm using https://www.kasmweb.com/. I'm wondering if there's anything that can be done client side without changing the resolution of the whole display.

Comment: I’m not familiar with that one.  I'm used to Citrix and VMware, but I can’t imagine it wouldn’t be configurable from the server side.